# send more than one model in MVC view if models are not related

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How to send more than one model to the View from Controller?

This seems to be a question that is asked so many times, still there is no good answer for newbyes like me (I have not found it).

One sollution I have found is to create some "Parent" model and return collection of Parent child models. I do not want to create any parent model as both my models are not related to each other.

For example, I have two models that do not have relations between them, they are seperate models, for example, `PersonModel` and `HardwareModel`. I have two partials views, one needs `PersonModel`, another needs `HardwareModel`.

I have `HomeController` that returns View. This view displays both partial views. So I need to send `PersonModel` to `_PersonPartialView`. And I need to send `HardwareModel` to `_HardwarePartialView`.

How to do this?

I believe there should be an option to send Collection of unrelated models to View, but how exactly?

**Edit:**
Some explantions: we have complicated decisions, based on those we show one ore both partial views. You can think like dashboard. User can see one ore more "dashobard" like panels. So they could be even unrelated to each other. So the real situation is more complicated as we have more than 2 different models and different partialviews.
Maybe I should have absolutely different approach.

Comment: you can use ViewData or ViewBag for that

Comment: you can create a new class containing both, or use Tuple<PersonModel,HardwareModel>

Comment: If this two models is not linked, why they is showed by single action method?

Comment: You models clearly are related as you have to supply both to your view. You are making life unnecessarily complicated for yourself.

Comment: They both can be used seperatly or together based on complicated conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this models is not linked, you should not return them from single controller method. If it should be showed on one page, you can load this partial views with `ajax` actions

one of examples how to do this [click](http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/11/13/improve-perceived-performance-of-asp-net-mvc-websites-with-async-partialviews/)

Comment: Can you give more details, please?

Comment: i added link with details.

Answer (score 2):

If the HomeView requires both PersonModel and HardwareModel, then those two combined are your model. So create eg

```
class HomeModel
{
    PersonModel person;
    HardwareModel hardware;
}
```

and you have your model.

**Update**

Based on the question update, if you have a dashboard-like page, then one option is to do away with the main view as you currently have it. Have a skeleton view, which defines the panel locations, but not their content. Then use AJAX calls to request partial views to populate the panels. That way, each partial view has its own model, separate from the others and you avoid having one view that need to know about all the models for all the partial views it might end up hosting.

Comment: @Matthias He *thinks* he doesn't want this. That is what is causing him problems...

Comment: I do not want this really, because based on different complex conditions I should show one ore both partial views. Such HomeModel doesn't fit in the whole ProjectStructure.

Comment: @renathy Without code it's difficult to understand what is wrong with your project structure, but if you are eg only using the person partial view, just use PersonModel. If you are using both via HomeView, then use a combined model.

Comment: And what if I have not two but say 20 models, and 20 partial views and can use them in different combinations? Then I have to create N models combining all possible ways? I just do no need combining model, I am asking about other sollutions.

Comment: @renathy In such a situation, your design would clearly be broken and would require a rethink. As I say, without code, it's difficult to understand why a combined model isn't the solution for your stated case.

Comment: I'm in total agreement with @DavidArno.  Your project architecture sounds broken.  It sounds like you are trying to shove too many pieces into one page.  But if we are mistaken and there really is a legitimate reason for this [and, please, update your question with details], then your only options are an encapsulation model (e.g. HomeModel) as David suggested, or a ViewBag-style model (e.g. HomerModel ICollection<Object>).  If you want a different answer you need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

We ended with putting abstract things that are part of several views, but not necessarily part of each model (e.g., cultures) into the ViewData / ViewBag. You can still access them in a strong-typed way by providing an extension method that encapsulates the view bag through a additional class. I'd suggest to put `HardwareModel` stuff into these, because it sounds like it's not the *main thing* on your web page.

```
public static HardwareSettings GetHardwareSettings (this HtmlHelper html)
{
  // simplified; add lazy instantiation...
  return (HardwareSettings) html.ViewData["hardware"];
}
```

This is for sure the best you can do. If this doesn't fit your problem, I suggest to reconsider your architecture, as it might be case that there are some flaws in it.